# Reducing typing overhead for an inherited constructor's parameter list

Tags: c#, constructor, copy-constructor

Is there any syntax and/or language feature for reducing the overhead in retyping the parameter list in an inherited constructor?

**Base Class**

```
public class Cartesian
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Cartesian(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

**Inherited Class**

```
public class Complex : Cartesian
{
    public int I { get; set; }

    // all this retyping becomes daunting and results in duplicate code
    public Complex(int x, int y, int i) : base(x, y)
    {
        I = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Compilers do not like ambiguity. What would you propose as an alternative?

Comment: Use a params int[] constructor?  I can show how if it seems like it might be an option worth exploring.

Comment: Short answer might be "no".  I suppose you could pass structs rather than individual arguments to at least bundle them up.  That'll get you some damage control.  But this example is the very struct you'd pass in.  So maybe complex constructor should take a cartesian instead of its individual arguments?  But what you sacrifice in the declaration of Complex, you put on the consumer of Complex so they have to say new Complex(new Cartesian(x,y), i).  So that's not great either.

Comment: Let me also say that I don't find your example to be a compelling case for reducing typing.  Maybe if there were 10+ arguments.  You only have to do it once.  Don't underestimate the ability to solve problems by doing work.  Editors with good macros or cut-and-paste / multi-insertion-point features are good at reducing typing too.

Comment: @DanWilson I don't know perhapse compiler support of a "append-base" keyword that could maybe insert a virtual constructor method, ctor_v that calls down to the child (though I don't think virtual methods are supposed to be called during construction so probably not the best idea).

Comment: @Wyck The constructor I'm dealing with takes thirteen parameters, and the subclass needs to add just three more.

Comment: 13 parameters is a clear sign that you should encapsulate some of these in a new class.  What is the relationship between these parameters?

Comment: @JamesFaix It's a database table/record abstraction.

Comment: Well you could pass in a `Cartesian` object into the constructor for `Cartesian`.

Comment: @DavidG **Wyck** explored this in his comments above.

Comment: Must be a good suggestion then!

Comment: @DanWilson I posted a quick and silly idea below.

Comment: @Wyck I think your proposed idea will solve the actual problem I was facing when trying to sub-class an object data mapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own ReSharper 8 there is a feature called [Generative Completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/Features/Completion.html#generative-completion).

> One form of code completion that made its appearance in ReSharper 8 is
>   called Generative Completion. The idea of generative completion is to
>   use code completion for code generation as a quicker, more direct
>   alternative to, say, the Generate menu.

In other words type `ctorp` and hit the tab key to generate the ctor

```
public class Complex : Cartesian
{
    public int I { get; set; }

    ctorp//tab key
}
```

generates

```
public Complex(int x, int y) : base(x, y)
{
     I = x;
}
```

You still have to fill in the derived class member(s) and do assignments, but it reduces overhead.

Comment: Besides direct language support I can't imagine there being anything much better than this. I really have to get 2017 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a some kind of workaround, but it just moves the duplicate code into an Init function so...:

**Base Class**

```
public class Cartesian
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    //public Cartesian(int x, int y) { Init(x, y); }

    public void Init(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;        
    }
}
```

**Inherited Class**

```
public class Complex : Cartesian
{
    public Cartesian Base { get {return base;} }

    public int I { get; set; }

    //public Complex(int i) { Init(i); }

    public Complex Init(int i)
    {
        I = i;

        return this;
    }
}
```

**Usage example**

```
var complex = (new Complex()).Init(i).Base.Init(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

From **P.Brian.Mackey** answer, if **`ctorp`** was replaced with a keyword, say **`base.ctorp:`**

```
public class Complex : Cartesian
{
    public int I { get; set; }

    //public Complex(int x, int y, int i) : base(x, y)
    public Complex(int i) : base.ctorp
    {
        I = i;
    }
}
```

Then have the compiler determine which constructor is being called based on the signature and substitute **`ctorp`** accordingly (and maybe have some explicative notation to complement):

```
var Complex = new Complex((x, y), i);
```

generates

```
    //public Complex(int i) : base.ctorp
    public Complex(int x, int y, int i) : base(x, y)
    {
        I = i;
    }
```

and

```
var Complex = new Complex(i);
```

generates

```
    //public Complex(int i) : base.ctorp
    public Complex(int i) : base()
    {
        I = i;
    }
```